# Inserting a specific number of blank lines

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to format my Honors Thesis, which has very specific formatting rules to prepare the manuscript for publication. For instance, on the Abstract page, I am required to place 3 blank lines above and below my name and degree information. At the moment, this is the code I have for the abstract page:

```
\newpage

\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
ABSTRACT \\

\vfill
\singlespacing
TITLE SINGLE-SPACED IN ALL CAPS, SAME SIZE AS THE REST OF THE TEXT

\vfill %Should be 3 blank lines here.

\doublespacing
My name \\
My department \\
My degree

\end{center}

\vfill %Should be 3 blank lines here.

Put text of the abstract here.

%The abstract must not exceed 250 words.
```

As you can see, right now I'm just using the `\vfill` command, which I think looks spectacular but doesn't fulfill the formatting requirements exactly (although it gets pretty close when the abstract is 250 words). I've considered using the `\vspace{}` command, but I don't know how long 3 lines of text in Times New Roman size 12 font would be. Right now I'm using TeXShop to edit this document, which is a .Rnw file (I'm going to use Sweave). Right now, the default spacing is double-spacing (Most of the thesis is required to be in double-spacing) using the setspace package.

Comment: `\vspace{3\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}` should work. But your center-environment will add some space, use better `\centering` if you want to avoid this.

Comment: a new question that covers this same topic: [Function to define how many lines to be displayed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80328/]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `\vspace*{3\baselineskip}` command for getting your requirement

Comment: Thanks - that seemed to work, although I did add `\vspace*{-\parskip}` and changed to `\centering` rather than the `\begin{center}` environment, as suggested by Ulrike. I also found that switching to `\singlespacing` after the "My department" line, and then switching back to `\doublespacing` before the text of the abstract, was helpful. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *bigbreak*:

```
alfa bravo
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
charlie delta
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
echo foxtrot
```

Comment: No, please don't.

Comment: @Johannes_B It would be great to mention, why.

Comment: It is just not a good idea to use `\bigbreak` several times. Also, depending on the font size, this gives (unexpected?) different results. `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
 alfa bravo
 \bigbreak
 \bigbreak
 \bigbreak
 charlie delta
 \bigbreak
 \bigbreak
 \bigbreak
 echo foxtrot
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
 alfa bravo
 \\[3\baselineskip]
 charlie delta\par
 \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
 echo foxtrot
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
`