# Function to define how many lines to be displayed

Tags: macros, loops

I have just made a command in my own document class wherein if I type: `\mline` it would automatically output 5 lines only.

My problem would be producing lines by just defining how many lines I want to be displayed by the command `\mline`.

### This is what I want to achieve

Examples:

- `\mline[10]` outputs 10 lines
- `\mline[3]` outputs 3 lines

### Code

```
\newcommand{\mline}{
    \noindent \null\hrulefill{} \\
    \null\hrulefill{} \\
    \null\hrulefill{} \\
    \null\hrulefill{} \\
    \null\hrulefill{} \\
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your definition of `\mline`?

Comment: This is how i make it thats why it produce 5 lines. How can i make more by just defining        it as argument using `\mline` command?                                              ##Code                                      \newcommand{\mline}
{
\noindent
\null\hrulefill{}   \\null\hrulefill{}   \\null\hrulefill{}   \\null\hrulefill{}   \\null\hrulefill{}   \
}

Comment: sorry! But Im glad of making me notified about that matter sir.

Comment: I think it's worth to have a look at here http://www.svenhartenstein.de/Software/LaTeX-Questionnaires . `\Qlines{5}`

Comment: related (though not identical): [Rule in textarea every n points](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70101/) and [Can LaTeX be used to make a sheet of blank lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24512/]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one possibility using a `\loop`, `\repeat` construct:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycont}

\newcommand\mline[1][5]{%
\setcounter{mycont}{0}
\par\noindent\loop
\ifnum\value{mycont}<#1
\null\hrulefill\\
\stepcounter{mycont}
\repeat\par}

\begin{document}

\mline

\mline[3]

\mline[8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I compiled my .tex file using `\document{myclass}` successfully without causing any error! Gracias!

Comment: @kayla I'm glad I could help. ¡De nada!

Answer (score 6):

The mandatory `expl3` answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mline}{ O{5} }
 {
  \par
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \hrulefill\par }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mline

\medskip

\mline[2]

\medskip

\mline[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version using `pgffor` for the looping:

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\mline}[1][5]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {%
         \par\noindent\null\hrulefill{}%
    }%
    \par% Thanks to Gonzalo Medina: Need this for the case of text following \mline.
}
 
\begin{document}
\bigskip
\mline
some text.% shows why the trailing \par is required.

\mline[3]

\bigskip
\mline[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to code this already using pgffor package but i always have a problem when i insert `\usepackage{pgffor}`in my own document class.

Comment: @kayla You need to provide more information about the problem you're having. Error message?

Comment: @kayla: As Qrrbrbirlbel said more information would be useful. However as this question is really not about using the `pgffor` package,  you could post a new question with the error message so people here can help you with that problem.  You could also try `usepackage{tikz}`, but I suspect the problem you have is that you have old packages somewhere.  Also, does this example as provided above yield the correct results for you?